# Generating standard xml and making request in Python/Django

Tags: python, xml, django

I need to generate a standard XML as follows using python:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<req:ShipmentValidateRequestAP xmlns:req="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema">

<root>
    <doc>
        <field1>some value1</field1>
        <field2>some vlaue2</field2>
    </doc>
</root>

</req:ShipmentValidateRequestAP>
```

And this needed to be requested to a server URL:

```
https://sampletest-ea.example.com/XMLShippingServlet
```

Can anybody please help me to implement this ?

Comment: OK. So what's stopping you?

Comment: I just want to know a perfect way to implement the same...

Comment: What do you need help with **specifically**. This is not the place to ask people to do your work for you, this is to ask for help with an _attempt that you already made_ that didn't work.

Comment: I tried it with urllib2  but with that i can generate only the '<root>,/root>' tags and the contents within that, actually i need help to create an xml file that starts with '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' and '<req:ShipmentValidateRequestAP>' tags as specified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can finish your work by the help of *http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html.*
It is a simple libary